# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'

Tags: c#, .net

I have following function which returns `true` or `false`:

```
public bool ValidateURL()
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt22.Text) & string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt33.Text))
   {
      return false;
   }
   else 
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Now following code is on a button but I am getting "*Operator cannot be applied*" error:

```
private void btn33_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ValidateURL==true)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Enter data");
   }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: All of the other answers are, of course, correct. But they all show testing the result of `ValidateURL()` against the literal `true`. There's really no reason to do this. You can omit the `== true` altogether, leaving you with simply: `if (ValidateURL()) {...}` The resulting code is much clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
private void btn33_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateURL())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter data");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Cody Gray pointed out, there's no real point in comparing "true" and the value returned by ValidateURL() (`ValidateURL() == true`). Nobody really does it and it just makes the code longer. When I answered the question, I just quickly copied, pasted and fixed OP's problem and this is why the comparison was there. While absolutely valid, it's not really needed. +1 Cody.

Comment: Might also be nice to add an explanation of why parenthesis are required (e.g. it's a method call) so that newbs may become learned! The best answers solve the problem but also explain why the problem occurred in the first place

Comment: I think you just did it quite nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if (ValidateURL==true)
```

to

```
if (ValidateURL() ==true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
if (ValidateURL())
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses. Should be `ValidateURL() == true`

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
if (ValidateURL() == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Google search of this error led me here. In my case, it was because I was referencing a new property in an ASP.NET MVC Razor page. The property had been added to my model, but I had forgotten to compile the project. The Razor compiler couldn't find the property, and was assuming I was trying to reference an extension method.

Once I compiled, the error cleared up.