# Foreach look for the first value in the entire list of records. cannot be applied to operator of type method group and bool

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am not sure how to write this linq express but I am trying to take a list of objects/records and find the first true value and set the property.

```
var test = recordList.First(s => s.myObject.isTrueValue == true);
```

isTrueValue  is the following

public over bool IsTrueValue() { return true}

when I build, I am getting the following error

> operation "==" cannot be applied to operator of type method group and bool

What I am trying to do is loop thru every record in the list and find the first isTrueValue field equal to true.

Comment: is s.myObject.isTrueValue a property or a method?

Comment: var test = recordList.Where(s => s.myObject.isTrueValue == true);

Comment: `== true` shouldn’t be written anyway. It’s always redundant, and conveys no useful information.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Just to be clear, it's always redundant when the LHS is of type `bool`. I quite often write that when the LHS is of type `bool?`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point but I’m not happy writing this with nullable values either, since in general usage this pattern is virtually always syntactic noise. I therefore prefer explicitly unwrapping the nullable (`Value` or `GetValueOrDefault()`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator '==' cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595897/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operand-of-type-method-group)

Comment: I'm sure that *sometime* (always) pasting an error message in *<your favorite search engine>* can (will) help

Answer (score 2):

`isTrueValue` is a method so you forgot the parentheses. Also, as Konrad Rudolph stated, `isTrueValue()` always returns true so you don't need the  `== true` expression:

```
var test = recordList.First(s => s.myObject.isTrueValue());
```

Answer (score -2):

Can tell me what's the data type of isTrueValue.
isTrueValue should be of type Boolean to compare with true.

Try this and let me know if this works for you.

```
var test = recordList.Where(s => s.myObject.isTrueValue == true).First();
```

Comment: It clearly states in the error message that the type of `isTrueValue` is method group

Comment: Note that answers shouldn't be used to obtain more information. I understand that you don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but that doesn't mean it's appropriate to use answers instead... it just means you need to wait for others to ask the questions, basically.